# CMD does not work with folders containing spaces

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I would like to run the cmd from VB.NEt. the problem is that it is not working with folder containing spaces

so, the code below does not work:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/C Copy /b D:\TEMP 1\*.MP3 C:\TEMP\ALL.MP3
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? If the problem is the cmd command then it shouldn't be in vb.net. Also you didn't close your parentheses and didn't use double-quotes for your paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it

the issue could be solved by enclosing folder paths with ["]. so,

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/C Copy /b ""D:\TEMP 1\*.MP3"" C:\TEMP\ALL.MP3")
```

will work fine

Comment: for VB.Net, in order to print ["], it should be headed by another ["]